# Laravel date / time comparsion

Tags: php, laravel

I’m stuck in the following problem:
In my database I have a field “date_time” which stores the date and time in the format `2020-09-08 10:15:00` In my API, data should now be output, which is newer than now.

Example:

`2020-08-09 17:30:00` -> to be issued

`2020-08-09 09:00:00` -> should not be issued (it has already passed)

My current code:

```
$viewingAppointments = ViewingAppointment::whereDate('date_time', '>=', Carbon::now('Europe/Berlin'))
->whereTime('date_time', '>=', Carbon::now('Europe/Berlin'))
->withCount('requests')
 ->get();
```

I’ve also tried the carbon comparators. That always worked well with the date. However, I can’t do time-filtering.

Comment: did you try 
whereTime('date_time', '>=', Carbon::now('Europe/Berlin')->format(your-time-formate))

Comment: Yeah, I tried, too. Then, however, it is filtered only by the time and no longer connected by date and time.

Comment: so you may try only where
where('date_time', '>=', Carbon::now('Europe/Berlin'))
and remove whereDate and whereTime

Comment: wtf. This works... I'm a bit stupid obviously. I relied on the whereDate function :( Sorry this was my mistake!

Comment: no prob!, We all do trivial mistakes sometimes:)) enjoy